# enzyme mount is breaking after upgrading react

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

i'm not sure how to explain the problem exactly because I myself don't understand it much.
I upgraded my **react/raect-dom to 16.6.3**
and after that all the tests in my project failed, first it was showing a warning about a polyfill for old browsers and after hours of internet digging I managed to get rid of that warning. However, all my tests are still failing.
I did some more digging and the majority recommended to upgrade enzyme-react-adapter and enzyme as well. so now I have also,
**enzyme 3.8.0** and **enzyme-adapter-react-16.3 1.6.1** .. but the tests are still failing.

This is the error msg i'm getting for one of the tests

```
Error: Enzyme Internal Error: unknown node with tag 7
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:225:13)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:189:70)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:189:70)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:189:70)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:189:70)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:189:70)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:189:70)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:162:21)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at childrenToTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:238:12)
    at toTree (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:184:19)
    at Object.getNode (node_modules\enzyme-adapter-react-16.3\build\ReactSixteenThreeAdapter.js:350:33)
    at new ReactWrapper (node_modules\enzyme\build\ReactWrapper.js:136:44)
    at Object.mount (node_modules\enzyme\build\mount.js:21:10)
    at Context.<anonymous> (C:/Users/EHU/sModal.test.jsx:119:36)
```

and this the test itself

```
it("should be shown with default values", () => {
        // Init

        // Action
        const wrapper = mount(<sModal.wrappedComponent {...provided}/>);

        // Test
        expect(wrapper.find("h2").text()).to.be.equal("TestHeader");
    });
```

I've been searching for a solution for the past six hours with no solid answer. someone suggested I import **core-js/es6/map** and **core-js/es6/set**. But that didn't work either, I don't even know how that relates to the problem in the first place. I think that the wrapper is not taking in the children nodes and that's the problem, but i'm not sure really.
Any help would be awesome

My code and all tests were running just fine before upgrading to **react 16**. I was running **enzyme 3.3.0** and **enzyme-adapter-react-16 1.1.1** before upgrading

Comment: Why  enzyme-adapter-react-16.3 and not  enzyme-adapter-react-16? Even the name suggests it's for 16.3. No wonder it doesn't work for 16.6.

Comment: @estus https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1900 suggested upgrading the adapter so i tried it and it still didn't work.
adapter 16, didn't work either btw, that's why I tried upgrading the adapter.

Comment: Comments in the issue clearly states that this was a temporary problem. enzyme-adapter-react-16 is the way to go. The problem is specific to your case. Could be mismatched package versions or else. Try to reinstall modules in the first place. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @estus you are correct, the problem is fixed now. thanks for the help.
I removed 16.3 adapter and installed 16 again, however it needed a different version to work with the enzyme upgrade. So now I'm running enzyme-adapter-react-16 at version 1.5.0
this fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

install the lastest version of `enzyme-adapter-react-16`

```
yarn add -D enzyme-adapter-react-16@last
```